# How to get appended output to refresh each time new input is entered?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to make an income calculator in which two HTML inputs in a form are added together and appended to a .div to give the total amount of income. It's successfully doing this, however as opposed to replacing the outputted total each time I enter a new number, it adds it onto the end of the previous total, e.g. £24£45.

How would I replace the output each time a new calculation is made?

On a side note, if I only enter a number into one of the input boxes I get an output of "NaN", is there any way to get rid of this and output simply the single number?

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".incomeform").blur(function () {
        primaryincome = $("#primaryincome").val();
        otherincome = $("#otherincome").val();
        totalincome = parseFloat(primaryincome) + parseFloat(otherincome);
        $(".incometotal").append("£" + totalincome)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--income-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="incometotal">Income Total: </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <form id="incomeform">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="primaryincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="primary income">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="otherincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="other income">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.html()` not `.append()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".incomeform").blur(function () {
        primaryincome = $("#primaryincome").val() || 0;
        otherincome = $("#otherincome").val() || 0;
        totalincome = parseFloat(primaryincome) + parseFloat(otherincome);
        $(".incometotal").html("£" + totalincome)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--income-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="incometotal">Income Total: </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <form id="incomeform">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="primaryincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="primary income">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="otherincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="other income">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Note that I also added `|| 0` so that you don't get `NaN` when only one input has a value.

Comment: Wow, those responses were fast! Thank you, I've made those changes and it's working great. I'll also look up the "|| 0" thing so I can understand exactly why it's working and what ti does. Thank you again.

Comment: All the `|| 0` means is that if the first value is false or falsy, then use 0. `||` is an `OR` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `span` in the `incometotal` div element, and then use `.html()`/`.text()` to set that element

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".incomeform").blur(function () {
        primaryincome = $("#primaryincome").val();
        otherincome = $("#otherincome").val();
        totalincome = parseFloat(primaryincome) + parseFloat(otherincome);
      
        $(".incometotal span").html("£" + totalincome)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--income-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="incometotal">Income Total: <span></span></div>
            <div class="row">
                 <form id="incomeform">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="primaryincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="primary income">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="otherincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="other income">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change last line:

```
$(".incometotal").html("£" + totalincome);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".incomeform").blur(function () {
        primaryincome = $("#primaryincome").val();
        otherincome = $("#otherincome").val();
        totalincome = parseFloat(primaryincome) + parseFloat(otherincome);
        $(".incometotal").html("£" + totalincome)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--income-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="incometotal">Income Total: </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <form id="incomeform">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="primaryincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="primary income">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="otherincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="other income">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You told it to add the new value onto whatever text is already there; that is what it is doing.

What you *want* it to do is replace whatever is there with the new value, including the label.  Like so:

```
$(".incometotal").text("Income Total: £" + totalincome);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find a suitable event for that.

Yeah, there isn't one.

There are [DOM Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL/Events#Mutation_DOM_events), but they aren't supported well cross-browser, and don't fire for form values anyway as those aren't reflected in attributes (except in IE due to a bug).

In Mozilla only, a JavaScript [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Object:watch) could be set on the value property to catch scripted changes. In IE only, a JScript [onpropertychange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956%28VS.85%29.aspx) handler could be set to catch both scripted and user-driven changes. In other browsers you would have to use your own interval poller to look for changes.

```
function watchProperty(obj, name, handler) {
    if ('watch' in obj) {
        obj.watch(name, handler);
    } else if ('onpropertychange' in obj) {
        name= name.toLowerCase();
        obj.onpropertychange= function() {
            if (window.event.propertyName.toLowerCase()===name)
                handler.call(obj);
        };
    } else {
        var o= obj[name];
        setInterval(function() {
            var n= obj[name];
            if (o!==n) {
                o= n;
                handler.call(obj);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}

watchProperty(document.getElementById('myinput'), 'value', function() {
    alert('changed!');
});
```

This is highly unsatisfactory. It won't respond to user-driven changes in Mozilla, it allows only one watched property per object in IE, and in other browsers the handler function will get called much later in execution flow.

It's almost certainly better to rewrite the parts of script that set `value` to call a setValue wrapper function instead, that you can monitor for changes you want to trap.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".incomeform").blur(function () {
        primaryincome = $("#primaryincome").val();
        otherincome = $("#otherincome").val();
        if( isNaN(primaryincome) || primaryincome == ""  ){primaryincome = 0;}
        if( isNaN(otherincome) || otherincome == ""  ){otherincome = 0;}
        totalincome = parseFloat(primaryincome) + parseFloat(otherincome);
        $("#total_amount").html("£" + totalincome)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--income-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="incometotal">Income Total: <span id="total_amount"></span></div>
            <div class="row">
                 <form id="incomeform">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="primaryincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="primary income">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="otherincome" class="incomeform" type="text" placeholder="other income">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Hello, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other answers before me you would

- **Use the `.html()` method instead of the `.append()` method**

However, I would suggest the following changes too, if they suit your needs:

1. **Use `type="number"` instead of type="text"** to ensure only numeric values are input. This also enables you to increment or decrement the current value.
2. **Use the `input` event instead of the `blur` event** to increase responsiveness.
3. **You can also set `value="0"` so you always have an initial value and, you can trigger the `input` event on page load to take advantage of these initial values.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.incomeform').on('input', function() {
        var f = $('#incomeform')[0];
        $('div.incometotal').html('£' + (+f.primaryincome.value + +f.otherincome.value) );
    })
    .trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--income-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="incometotal">Income Total: </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <form id="incomeform">
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="primaryincome" class="incomeform" type="number" value="0" placeholder="primary income">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <input id="otherincome" class="incomeform" type="number" value="0" placeholder="other income">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```